# Issue with renaming Attachments with Accents in File Name- Bulk upload

Tags: apex, community, data-loader, attachment

I am working on bulk loading of Attachments and as per SF documentation, after Data export, I renamed Attachment names using 'bat' file. Everything went fine except for the Attachments that has **Accent** characters in File name. If I save bat file with any other encoding than 'ANSI', bat file doesn't work. But with ANSI, Accent characters are replaced with junk characters and Data loader isn't able to recognize due to difference in file names. Is there a solution for this issue, other than replacing all Accent characters with normal English letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to use chcp command to change codepage before running the bat file in command line interface as in below link.

https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html

I used chcp 65000 and it was able to replace most diacritics with few exceptions like Chinese letters.!!